# Dynamically drawing the polygon formed by nearest points to @map_extent_center in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polygon-creation, geometry-generator, knn

From a DEM raster layer I created a set of random points and informed each point with the value of 'ELEVATION'.

I also used the following expression to connect the 10 points closest to the @map_extent_center with the lowest ELEVATION value. This is a variant of the expression developed by the user [Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel) in the question '[Drawing an arc with length proportional to a distance in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/473510/drawing-an-arc-with-length-proportional-to-a-distance-in-qgis)':

```
case 
when 
    $geometry = 
    closest_point(
        collect($geometry),
        @map_extent_center
    )
then
    with_variable(
    'min',
    array_sort (array_agg (ELEVATION),0)[10],

    collect_geometries(
        array_slice( 
            array_agg( 
                difference(
                    make_line($geometry, @map_extent_center),
                    make_circle(@map_extent_center,400)
                ), 
                filter:=ELEVATION<@min,
                order_by:=length(make_line($geometry, @map_extent_center))
            ),
            0,
            10
        )
    ))
end
```

I also use the `difference` argument to represent a 400 meter circle that is intended to show the centroid extent of the selected points:

[image]

I would like, if possible, to reuse this expression to draw the polygon formed by the points. I show what I want to say with a screenshot::

[image]

Comment: What does "the 10 points closest to the @map_extent_center with the lowest ELEVATION value" exactly mean? This is unclear, you should be more clear about how the condition is defined. The "10 closest" points are lower than... what? What if the closest 10 points are not lower? This makes no sense as it is written now.

Comment: Does your question mean (so much I tried to understand from the expression): "Connect the map_extent_center to the 10 (11?) closest point, but consider only points that have an elevation smaller than the top 10 highest elevation values in the dataset. Create a polygon (concave hull?) around these points."

Comment: I answer these questions in the comments to your solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply create the concave hull around the points you have with function [`concave_hull()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#concave-hull):

[image]

```
with_variable(
    'min',
    array_sort (array_agg (ELEVATION),0)[10],
    concave_hull(
       collect_geometries(
            array_slice( 
                array_agg( 
                    $geometry, 
                    filter:=ELEVATION<@min,
                    order_by:=length(make_line($geometry, @map_extent_center))
                ),
                0,
                10
            )
        ),
        0.3
    )
)
```

However, I don't understand your whole task and the expression you use. It seems illogic to me why e.g. you use a `case...when` condition that is unnecessary - you could leave it away and reduce the expression to its core (the part included in the `then` part) to get the same points. I also don't see what this expression should be good for, but that's another point.

And, by the way: you want the 10 closest point to the @map_extent_center. However, your expression returns 11 points as you use the `array_slice()` function with array-index 0 to 10. Array indices start with 0 for the first element, so you have indices 0 to 10 / element 1 to 11...

Comment: I try to clarify some of your doubts. Regarding the use of the `case`...`when` condition, I agree with you and correct and reduce my initial expression. Regarding the use of this expression, I am helping in a dowsing project to find leaks and natural water points and we work in the field. In field work conditions, we need a fast and dynamic vector visualization of slope orientations and low altitude areas. I have designed this solution that we are testing. It may not be quite right. We will see how successful it is.
I will take it into account your clarification about `arrays`.

Comment: In real time field work, there is not much time for complex GIS analysis and the working conditions are sometimes difficult. With this vector visualization, technicians and operators do not have to think too much and can make decisions quickly. It should be noted that the dowser has not a scientific evidence, but it is the most reliable method for finding water leaks. The concave-hull object is perfect. We will see how the tests work and what feedback I get from the workers

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifications!

Comment: Same to you. Thank you very much for your help in providing solutions that work perfectly