# Drawing an arc from coordinate 0,0 to the median distance cluster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

Starting from points layer with the fields "DISTANCE" and "CLUSTER_ID".

"DISTANCE" field stores the straight line distance value of each point relative to the 0,0 coordinate.

"CLUSTER_ID" field stores the Cluster id.

As you can see in the screenshot, each point is labeled with its distance `"DISTANCE"` and I also label each cluster with the mean distance with the following expression `array_mean (array_agg ("DISTANCE", group_by:="CLUSTER_ID"))`:

[image]

My goal is to use the Geometry Generator to the points layer and with the computed mean distance value of each cluster id to draw, for each cluster id, an arc from coordinate 0,0 to the mean distance cluster id, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

[Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel) user's solution applied:

[image]

Is it possible to cut the circle in a vertical half left side as shown in this handmade reproduction?

[image]

Comment: Should be possible using wedge buffer, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I think with the `wedge_buffer` object it might be possible to achieve this goal. I think the solution could be similar to the one proposed in the question [link]https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/473510/drawing-an-arc-with-length-proportional-to-a-distance-in-qgis[link]
Unfortunately, my level of expressions development with `wedge_buffer` object is still very early and for this reason I haven't tried an own solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `make_circle()` function with the point (0,0) as center and the mean distance as radius:

```
make_circle( 
    make_point (0,0),
    array_mean (array_agg ("DISTANCE", group_by:="CLUSTER_ID"))
)
```

---

You could also create a convex hull around each point cluster including the center, then intersect this hull with the circle to only get an arc:

*Red: convex hull; blue line: intersection with circles:*
[image]

```
intersection (
    boundary(
        make_circle( 
                make_point (0,0),
                array_mean (array_agg ("DISTANCE", group_by:="CLUSTER_ID")),
        100
        )
    ),
    convex_hull( 
        union (
            geometry(get_feature_by_id ('center',1)),
            collect($geometry,group_by:=CLUSTER_ID)
        )
    )
)
```

---

For a half circle, use `wedge_buffer()`:

```
 wedge_buffer( 
    make_point (0,0),
    90,
    180,
    array_mean (array_agg ("DISTANCE", group_by:="CLUSTER_ID"))
)
```

[image]

And from there, to get rid of the vertical lines on the left, intersect with the boundary of the circle:

```
with_variable (
    'dist',
    array_mean (array_agg ("DISTANCE", group_by:="CLUSTER_ID")), 
    intersection (
        boundary(
            make_circle( 
                make_point (0,0),
                @dist,
                100
            )
        ),
        wedge_buffer( 
            make_point (0,0),
            90,
            180,
            @dist
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

---

And to get only the arc for the angle where the points are distributed:

[image]

```
case
when $id = minimum ($id, group_by:="CLUSTER_ID")
then intersection (
    boundary(
        make_circle( 
            geometry(get_feature_by_id ('center',1)),
            array_mean (array_agg ("DISTANCE", group_by:="CLUSTER_ID")),
            100
        )
    ),
    with_variable(
        'azim',
        array_sort(
            array_foreach(
                geometries_to_array (
                    collect($geometry,group_by:=CLUSTER_ID)
                ),
                degrees(
                    azimuth(
                        geometry(get_feature_by_id ('center',1)),
                        @element
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        wedge_buffer(
            geometry (get_feature_by_id ('center',1)),
            (@azim[-1]+@azim[0])/2,
            @azim[-1]-@azim[0],
            array_mean (array_agg ("DISTANCE", group_by:="CLUSTER_ID"))
        )
    )
)
end
```

**Possible new capability or improvement**

[See here for a further improvement and an additional question by the initial OP of the question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/474579/88814).

Comment: Excellent. Your `convex_hull` proposal greatly improves the visualization

Comment: Is it possible to cut the circle in a vertical half on the left side as shown in my handmade visualization? I am adding a screenshot with the meaning of my question

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Last question: I work with QGIS version 3.28.11 LTR Firenze and the `get_feature_by_id` function is not available for this version. I think this function is available from version 3.32. Is there any substitute function for get_feature_by_id to make it work?

Comment: `get_feature_by_id` exists since long time before 3.28, see e.g. here documentation for version 3.16: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#get-feature-by-id Maybe typing error? In fact you could also replace this part of the expression with `make_point (0,0)` in your case is in  the first example with the circle.

Comment: `get_feature_by_id` was introduced in QGIS 3.0 in Feb 2018 - 6 years from now. https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#feature-new-expression-functions

Comment: I confirm that I was making a typing error and I check that in my QGIS version I have available the function `get_feature_by_id`. I have managed to implement your solutions

Comment: @Babel very useful. Clould you add the expression is used to draw the dashed lines in the last solution?

Comment: @Acperience This is simply the wedge buffer's boundary (including the arc, but hidden in the image). So use the expression in the answer, but delete the `intersection` function - delete lines 3-10 but keep the `then` statement and also delete the last closing bracket `)` (2nd last line). Like this, you get the wedge buffer. Style it as `Outline: Simple line` or enclose the `wedge_buffer()` i a `boundary()` function.

Comment: I have modified user @Babel expression to work with a multi-dot layer. I have added the expression to the answer, but I find a problem which I describe in the same answer. Could you help me to fix this bug so that this improvement works correctly?

Comment: Thank you for the notice. I also can't see the edit I made. I don't know why it hasn't been posted. I'll try again

Comment: Done and sorry for the mistake

Comment: OK, I deleted your edit and made a link to your question to keep it clean.