# Get only the arc for the angle where the points are distributed for multi point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

According to the question [Drawing an arc from coordinate 0,0 to the median distance cluster in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474417/drawing-an-arc-from-coordinate-0-0-to-the-median-distance-cluster-in-qgis), I have modified the last expression of the user [Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel) so that it can work with a 'center' layer with several points and the `overlay_nearest` function:

```
case
when $id=minimum($id,group_by:="CLUSTER_ID",filter:="CLUSTER_ID" is not NULL)
then
    with_variable(
        'azim',
        array_sort(
            array_foreach(
                geometries_to_array (
                    collect($geometry,group_by:=CLUSTER_ID)
                ),
                degrees(
                    azimuth(
                        overlay_nearest('center',$geometry)[0],
                        @element
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        wedge_buffer(
            overlay_nearest('center',$geometry)[0],
            (@azim[-1]+@azim[0])/2,
            @azim[-1]-@azim[0],
            array_mean (array_agg ("DISTANCE", group_by:="CLUSTER_ID"))
        )
    )
end
```

Screenshot:

[image]

As you can see the visualization is correct, with the exception of the blue-purple cluster that I point out with an arrow in the following screenshot:

[image]

It seems that in this case the `wedge_buffer` function with clusters having points at 0 degrees and 360 degrees returns an arc that is almost a circle.
As you can see, I have manually modified the points position and the expression returns the expected result.

[image]

Is it possible to adjust this issue, for example adjusting the part of the expression where the `wegde_buffer` works to take into account and correct this possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following expression to get a bounding box (much easier than the wedge buffers - for those, see below):

[image]

The expression for this convex hull looks like this:

```
case
when $id=minimum($id,group_by:="CLUSTER_ID",filter:="CLUSTER_ID" is not NULL)
then
    convex_hull(
        union(
            overlay_nearest ('center',$geometry)[0],
            collect ($geometry, group_by:=CLUSTER_ID)
        )
    )
end
```

---

To get the correct wedge buffers, use the expression below:

[image]

```
case
when $id=minimum($id,group_by:="CLUSTER_ID",filter:="CLUSTER_ID" is not NULL)
then
    with_variable(
        'azim',
        array_sort(
            array_foreach(
                geometries_to_array (
                    collect($geometry,group_by:=CLUSTER_ID)
                ),
                degrees(
                    azimuth(
                        overlay_nearest('center',$geometry)[0],
                        @element
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        wedge_buffer(
            overlay_nearest('center',$geometry)[0],
            if (
                (@azim[-1]-@azim[0]) <= 180,
                (@azim[-1]+@azim[0])/2,
                (array_min (array_filter (@azim, @element > 180)) - 360 +
                array_max (array_filter (@azim, @element<180)))/2
            ),
            if (
                (@azim[-1]-@azim[0]) <= 180,
                @azim[-1]-@azim[0],
                360-array_min (array_filter (@azim, @element>180))
                + array_max (array_filter (@azim, @element<180))
            ),
            array_mean (array_agg ("DISTANCE", group_by:="CLUSTER_ID"))
        )
    )
end
```